# Why isn't high functioning autism recognized by the DSM-5 or the ICD-10?

Tags: autism

I was looking at this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-functioning_autism and it said that. Aspergers is also closely related to high functioning autism but it is also not recognized anymore. Does this mean that neither of them are a "thing" anymore? Would diagnosing someone with either of these labels be inaccurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asperger's being "subsumed" in DSM-5 is not the whole story. There's indeed a new DSM-5 coding for the severity of the disorder. But applying the DSM-5 actual clinical criteria results in fewer people being diagnosed with autistic spectrum disorders, and the reduction is more significant for the mild versions (such as Asperger's):

A 2014 mini-review looking at 12 [papers concluded](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s40489-014-0033-6):

> The application of DSM-5 diagnostic criteria resulted in an approximately one third reduction in Autism Spectrum Disorders. The reduction was approximately two thirds for mild forms of Autism.

So yeah, the DSM-5 take (intentional or not) is that a lot of "Aspies" don't have a level of dysfunction that raises to the (DSM-5) bar of a mental *disorder *.

However in an astute form of politicking, people with an existing Asperger's diagnosis were "grandfathered in" by the DSM-5. From the same review:

> The American Psychiatric Association partially acknowledged
>   the exclusion of mild forms of ASD when the added
>   rider to the diagnostic criteria was that “Individuals with a
>   well-established DSM-IV diagnosis of autistic disorder,
>   Asperger’s disorder, or pervasive developmental disorder not
>   otherwise specified should be given the diagnosis of autism
>   spectrum disorder”, but this approach to diagnosis of autismis
>   strange. It enables individuals who previously were diagnosed
>   with ASD to continue to be eligible for services, but results in
>   two odd consequences. First, consider two individuals with
>   identical symptoms who meet DSM-IV criteria for ASD, one
>   of whom was diagnosed before the publication of DSM5 and
>   one diagnosed after: The first will be diagnosed with ASD and
>   eligible for services, but the second will not. The second
>   consequence is that the meaning of the DSM5 term ASD is
>   obfuscated as it refers to different entities using the same term.

And a [2016 meta-analysis](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40489-016-0070-4) confirms the effect of stricter criteria (using twice as many studies as the 2014 review):

> Our meta-analysis measured the percentage of people with an ASD diagnosis from the DSM-IV or DSM-IV-TR obtaining an ASD diagnosis from the DSM-5. All 24 studies identified indicated a reduction in the number of people with a DSM-IV or DSM-IV-TR ASD diagnosis being eligible for a DSM-5 ASD diagnosis, a 35 and 37 % reduction respectfully. Our meta-analysis also showed that those with a DSM-IV-TR or DSM-IV diagnosis of PDD-NOS were the least likely to qualify for a DSM-5 ASD diagnosis at 26 and 47 % followed by 55 and 19 %, respectfully of people with Asperger syndrome, and 80 and 87 %, respectfully of people with an autism diagnosis.

A more recent [(2017) study](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10803-016-2942-y) on Australian children (where the use of DSM is mandated by certain government programs) found that DSM-5 did seem to stop to the previously increasing trend in rising autism diagnoses:

> De-identified data for 32,199 children aged under 7 years between 2010 and 2015 was utilised. [...] The incidence of autism increased from 2010 to 2013, and then plateaued to 2015. A significant trend-relative reduction in the number of children registered to receive autism-specific funding was evident post 2013, suggesting the more stringent DSM-5 criteria may have curbed the trend of increasing diagnoses over time.

---

As for why the DSM-5 removed the separate criteria (including Asperger's), quoting from the last paper:

> These previously distinct diagnostic
>   categories were removed in light of empirical data
>   that questioned the reliability and validity of these subtypes
>   ([Daniels et al. 2011](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10803-010-1031-x); [Lord 2012](https://doi.org/10.1001/archgenpsychiatry.2011.148); [Macintosh and Dissanayake
>   2004](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15055363); [Mahjouri and Lord 2012](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11920-012-0327-2)).

Whether this was the right thing to do or not... it depends who you ask. Asperger's diagnosis definitely has its supporters, at least one of whom even [predicted its return](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10803-013-1839-2) in the next version of the DSM.

Answer (score 2):

High-functioning autism along with Asperger's syndrome were both subsumed by Autism Spectrum Disorder in the DSM-5 in 2013.  The Autism Society has [a good page on the distinctions and history](http://www.autism-society.org/what-is/aspergers-syndrome/) of these various diagnoses.